# How to pass data from app.component.ts to its app.module.ts in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Due to the requirements of project I need to send data value **dataOne** in app.component.ts to its app.module.ts so that I can store it in variable **moduleValue**. Please refer code below and suggest how can achieve this transfer of data within files.

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'formcheck';

  dataOne: any;

  getValues(val: any) {
    console.warn(val);
    this.dataOne = val;
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

let moduleValue: any;

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
  
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to store the value in your module and e.g., not in a service?

Comment: @Batajus after that I have to inject inside some library. I just want data to be stored inside moduleValue, please suggest however possible

Comment: if you don't care about proper separation of concerns that just do whatever is easiest - attach the value to `window`

Comment: @devmiles.com please could you share some example?

Comment: look at the answer from Mohamed Moumen below, his solution is even better because it's not introducing a global variable.

Comment: @devmiles.com the DATA is returning the default empty string value and not getting updated as val changes. Any idea how to overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that you declare a variable or an observable in a service, however, since you mentioned that you need to do this within the same files you might want to export a variable from your component and import it into your module like so:

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'formcheck';

  dataOne: any;

  getValues(val: any) {
    console.warn(val);
    this.dataOne = val;
    DATA = this.dataOne;
  }
}

export var DATA = '';
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DATA } from './app.component';

let moduleValue: any;

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but export var DATA is not getting updated even if the value inside getValues() changes. Could you suggest how to update data dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution using service, I used **BehaviorSubject** for dynamic updation of value.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9pitmh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fdata.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts